# How to create filter for checkbox in kendo Grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I need to have a filter on my kendo grid for check box.
The checkbox is a Non-Bound column. Using checkbox I select the corresponding row.
I need to have a filter to get all the rows which are selected and not selected on the checkbox

```
columns.Template(@<text> </text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  class='chkbx'").Title("Select");
```

Kindly help....

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve such functionality is to extend your data source and add boolean column in your datasource definition. Then you will able to apply custom filter like this:

```
dataSource.filter({ field:"Field", operator: "eq", value: true });
```

As far I know - there is no build kendo way to manage filtering unbounded columns.